# avocado plant from water to soil

Tags: transplanting, avocado

I have just potted a home grown avocado plant from water to soil and day 2 of repotting and the leaves are drooping. Should I move back into water or just wait and hope for the best?

[image: Plant]

Comment: @alephzero if you have an answer, please post an answer. Answering in comments is discouraged for many reasons, one of them is because it bypasses the quality control of the voting system, another that comments are temporary by design.

Answer (score 2):

I would make sure the soil is quite moist. The plant has been living in water for a while and now that it was transferred to drier soil it is in shock. So just water the plant quite heavily and the leaves should perk up in a day or two, I've even had plants perk up in a matter of minutes after being watered.

You can also remove the barbecue skewers, those are not needed anymore. Hope this helps!

EDIT: Oh, also I forgot to mention, please move it away from the cold window, it definitely doesn't like that.